# What is the explicit formula for the general term of the sequence?

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A sequence $\{a_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is defined recursively by

$$a_0 = 1, a_1 = 1$$
$$a_n = 5a_{n-1}-6a_{n-2}, \text{ for } n \ge 2 $$

Find an explicit formula for the general term $A_n$.

So, I want to let the vector

$
 \begin{equation*}
 A_n = \begin{bmatrix} a_n\\ 
 a_{n-1}\\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{equation*}
$

Then if I can find a relation between $A_n$ and $A_{n-1}$ using a $2 \times 2$ matrix I believe I'm close.  Once the relation is found I could use eigenvector diagonalization to possibly find the explicit formula for $A_n$?

There should be a relation, I believe, between the characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$ matrix to the coefficients of

$a_n - 5a_{n-1} + 6a_{n-2} = 0$

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$
A_n = \begin{bmatrix} 
a_n \\ a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix} 
5a_{n-1} - 6a_{n-2} \\ a_{n-1}
\end{bmatrix} 
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -6 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{n-1}\\ a_{n-2}
\end{bmatrix} = 
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & -6 \\ 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix} A_{n-1}. 
$$

Answer (score 0):

To compare with the matrix method a classic method is given here. Let $a_{n} = r^{n}$ to obtain
\begin{align}
a_{n} &= 5 \, a_{n-1} - 6 \, a_{n-2} \\
r^{n} &= 5 \, r^{n-1} - 6 \, r^{n-2} \\
r^{2} &= 5 \, r - 6 \\
r &\in \{2, 3\}.
\end{align}
From this it is given that $a_{n} = c_{0} \, 2^{n} + c_{1} \, 3^{n}$. Using $a_{0} = a_{1} = 1$ then the solution becomes
$$a_{n} = 2^{n+1} - 3^{n}.$$